# How can I make multiple meshes in unity by script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I made a water swirl and surface mesh in unity by script, and now I need to add wall which is a simple mesh. But I don't know how to add another mesh though. I wanted to find something like meshfilter.addmesh, but there is no such methods though. I 'm wondering how can I add another mesh or mesh filter to add that wall. I use C# btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description of your problem (which is not clear enough) it looks like you should create another game object with MeshFilter and MeshRenderer components (you can do it either by hands or by script) for your wall.

If for some reason you REALLY want to have several meshes in one MeshFilter then your only option is to use submeshes (see [Mesh.subMeshCount](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh-subMeshCount.html), [Mesh.SetIndices](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh.SetIndices.html), [Mesh.SetTriangles](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh.SetTriangles.html), [Renderer.materials](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html) and maybe [Mesh.CombineMeshes](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh.CombineMeshes.html)).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I didn't use anothet meshfilter is because i don't know how to get another meshfilter because in the tutorial which i adapted it's like filter=getgameobject<meshfilter>().There seems nothing to specify which meshfilter i can get. do you know how to get the specific meshfilter？thank you. use phone to write this so format is horrible

Comment: Man, you really need to go through a couple more tutorials :)

Comment: To begin with: GameObject.Find(name of game object).GetComponent<MeshFilter>()